# Python json to csv: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'"

Tags: python, json, csv

So I have been attempting to create a file to convert json files to csv files using a template i found online. However, I keep receiving the following error:

header = User.keys()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Here is the code I'm using:

```
# Python program to convert
# JSON file to CSV
 
 
import json
import csv
 
 
# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open('/Users/jhillier5/Downloads/mentalhealthcheck-in-default-rtdb-export (1).json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
 
User_data = data['User']
 
# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')
 
# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)
 
# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file
count = 0
 
print(User_data)
print(type(User_data))

for User in User_data:
    if count == 0:
 
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = User.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
 
    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(User.values())
 
data_file.close()
```

I simply don't understand why there is a string object and not a dict. I double checked and User_data is stored as a dict but i still get the error.

The json is organised in the following format:

```
{
  "User" : {
    "-MlIoVUgATqwtD_3AeCb" : {
      "Aid" : "1",
      "Gender" : "1",
      "Grade" : "11",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this for loop

```py
for User in User_data:
    if count == 0:
 
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = User.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
 
    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(User.values())
```

You are iterating through `User_data`, so `User` will be `["MlIoVUgATqwtD_3AeCb", ...]`. In order to get the keys of that user data you should index it this way -

```py
header = User_data[User].keys()
```